# How to use different gcc versions with cmake?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake

for some reason I need to use different gcc versions with cmake.
In my case I want to use gcc 9 for cmake init and gcc 8 for cmake --build.

I trie dusing toolchain file like:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_INIT "/usr/bin/gcc-9")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_INIT "/usr/bin/g++-9")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")
```

But this doesn't work. cmake always uses gcc-9 for cmake build in this case. Does someone know a working way?

Comment: "I want to use gcc 9 for cmake init and gcc 8 for cmake --build" - Do you mean that you want to specify gcc 9 when **configure** the project, but use gcc 8 for **build**? This has no sense: CMake configures the project for the compiler, which will be used for build.

Comment: Yes, cmake init configures the compiler AND does some other stuff like creating binaries with the compiler found at cmake init time start. For this I need to use gcc-9 (because gcc-8 fails here). But for cmake --build I then want to use gcc-8

Comment: `gcc 9 for cmake init and gcc 8 for cmake --build.` What is "cmake init"? Do you mean cmake configuration stage? Check documentation. What is "cmake init time start"? `I need to use gcc-9 (because gcc-8 fails here` Why not fix gcc-8 then? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: "does some other stuff like creating binaries with the compiler found at cmake init time start" - You probably mean that CMake tries to use the compiler for several "small" projects for check whether the compiler works and for determine its properties. "because gcc-8 fails here" - So you need to understand why gcc-8 doesn't pass the checks and modify your toolchain for fix these issues. By attempting to fake a compiler to CMake you are solving the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The problem here arise from qt which no longer supports gcc8. In cmake init (qt) it creates some binaries used at build time later. These created binaries give segfault in gcc-8 case. So I wanted to use gcc-9 to create these binaries and gcc-8 to build qt itself

Comment: Have you tried/considered generating ordinary makefiles and using the CC and CXX environment variables? In other words: init cmake with GCC-9 in $CXX and afterwards build with GCC-8 in $CXX?

Comment: Not sure if cmake follows all symlinks to the end. If it doesn't theoretically `/usr/bin/g++-9` is a symlink to the real compiler path and that symlink could be redirected to a different compiler after doing the cmake configuration step. You'll almost certainly get yourself in trouble by doing this though. The fact that the cmake logic has a check that prevents the usage of gcc8 means there's probably a reason for this. Likely qt would fail compilation even if you resort to the hack described. Since gcc9 seems available to you, why not use it though???

Comment: Yes, gcc-9 is available to me, but, in our project, gcc-8 is set for some reason.